# Unit тест для приложения Android с работающим HandlerThread

Tags: android, юнит-тесты

После изучения материалов по тестированию в Android возникли сомнения что такое возможно. Итак...

Есть приложение с неким глобальным объектом с множеством состояний. По вызову метода формируется команда, которая, выполняясь в `HandlerThread` меняет состояние этого объекта. По своему завершению, эта команда вызывает каллбэк в объекте со специальным интерфейсом.

Есть желание сделать множество unit тестов для тестирования данного глобального объекта через подачу ему различных команд и проверку состояния после срабатывания каллбэка. По идее, это обычный рабочий функционал приложения.

Такое вообще возможно сделать? Если возможно, было-бы интересно увидеть пример такого тестирования или хотя-бы узнать направление, в котором имеет смысл вести поиск.

Comment: Unit тест может как-то узнать что callback был вызван?

Comment: Вопрос в том числе и в этом.

Comment: Хотя, я нашел как отлавливать сам факт вызова каллбэка:
`Callback callback = mock(Callback.class);
verify(callback).onComplete(any(Data.class));`

Но это не решает самой проблемы тестирования. Т.к. мне нужно анализировать состояние глобального объекта ПОСЛЕ вызова каллбэка.

Comment: Есть идея в тесте переписать исполнительный механизм на предмет замены исполнения команды в HandlerThread на обычное исполнение в том-же потоке. В какой-то степени, это должно решить проблему. Но, опять-же, это не решает проблемы тестирования корректной работы параллельного исполнителя команд.

Comment: Зачем все так усложнять? Используйте, к примеру, `AtomicBoolean` для синхронизации между потоками. И тестируйте многопоточно. Главное, чтобы этот ваш глобальный обьект был тестабельным.

Comment: Евгений, т.е. вы предлагаете для тестирования менять код рабочего класса? Можете в качестве ответа разместить возможный пример такого тестирования с использованием HandlerThread?

Comment: Зачем менять, просто надо иметь возможность для callback inject, иначе как тестировать? А HandlerThread это или любой другой, не суть важно.

Comment: Евгений, все-таки, нужен пример. На словах как-то не совсем понятно что вы имеете ввиду.